# Custom Taxonomy Query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have setup two custom taxonomies for a custom post type that I have created. The post type is called beer, and the two taxonomies are country and brewers.

I would like to list them like this.

```
 Country
 -->Brewers
 ----->Beers
```

I can pull the countries using this code.

```
    $terms_country = get_terms('country');
    foreach ($terms_country as $term_country) {
    echo "<h3 class=\"country-heading\" id=\"".$term_country->slug."\">";
    echo '<a href="/beers/country/' . $term_country->name . '">' . $term_country->name       . '</a>';
    echo "</h3>";
```

I need to query the country term to list the Brewers that have that taxonomy attached to the post as well.

Comment: something like this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70831/get-terms-that-contain-posts-that-in-turn-belong-to-other-terms

Comment: That appears to get me the data when I dump it. How do I format it so that I can use it in a list? I am a PHP noob!

Comment: added a usage example as an answer

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This answer is supposed to be in addition to the answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70831/get-terms-that-contain-posts-that-in-turn-belong-to-other-terms#answer-71168)

The function used returns an array of all the items, so the best way to display them is to use a foreach loop. As a usage example

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_col(....); //copy the line from the aforementioned answer

if($result) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($result as $term) {
        echo '<li>' . $term . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

In case you changed the `get_col` to `get_results` to query more details about the terms, the foreach loop changes just a little

```
    foreach($result as $term) {
        echo '<li>' . $term->name . ' with slug ' . $term->slug . '</li>';
    }
```

Comment: This only lists the first grouping. It is doing almost the same thing as wp_list_categories. How can I get the Brewers looped inside of this?

Comment: Maybe i didn't exactly get you, `wp_list_categories` lists all the terms. This however, lists the countries terms with attached posts that also have brewers attached

Comment: or are you looking for [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms). It returns the terms in a specific taxonomy attached to a post

Comment: All of the posts are going to have both taxonomies attached so that doesn't really matter in this case. I need to list them as described in my first post. All countries then all brewers then the posts by brewer.

Comment: For that i think maybe you may loop through the posts of country & use `get_the_terms` to get all the brewers but there must be another more efficient way

Comment: I just want it to work at this point. Do you have a way to do that that I can see?

Comment: Yes, first use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) inside your original country loop to get all beers of that country. Then loop through them & use `get_the_terms` everytime to get all brewers in an array format, then display the brewers just queried & the posts you queried previously

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I can't work with that. Can I just pay you something to get this working?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't do it but you'll probably get a reply on this from someone else soon