# Get list of terms that have posts in another term

Tags: wp-query, terms, tax-query

I have a product attribute called "color" and when I am on the archive page (e.g. color=blue) I want to display a list of all the parent product categories that contain products with that attribute, color=blue.

I tried using get_queried_object_id() to get the archive term (blue), in conjunction with get_terms(), however I couldn't figure it out. I'd like to reiterate that I want to retrieve the list of terms and not the posts.

If anyone can lead me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70831/get-terms-that-contain-posts-that-in-turn-belong-to-other-terms) seems similar to what I want, however it uses wpdb, and want to use a regular query.

I was tried doing something like this, to get a list of all posts that are in both taxonomies (pa_color and product category), but I am not sure how to get a list of just categories.

```
$current_color = get_queried_object_id();

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'      => array(
                               array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => $current_color,
                                        'operator' => 'AND'
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => $cats
                                    )
                                )
                        ) );
```

Comment: Paste a code that you used

Comment: @anton Iadded some code to the post, however I couldn't get anything to work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `'operator' => 'AND'` with `'relation'=>'AND'`

Updated Code Snippet:

```
$current_color = get_queried_object_id();

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'      => array(
                              'relation' => 'AND'
                               array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => $current_color,
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => $cats
                                    )
                                )
                        ) );
```

Reference : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters ( **Multiple Taxonomy Handling** )

Edit 1: You can edit above query to return only `ids` ( 'fields' => 'ids' ) and use `get_terms` for those IDs to get the list of categories

```
get_terms( array( 
   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
   'object_ids' => $posts_matching_criteria
);
```

Ref 1 : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Ref 2 : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: Thanks @ViralP, however, won't this just output the POSTS that have these 2 taxonomies in common? I need it to output a list of product categories that contain products with the particular color.

Comment: @Edegist : If I have understood the requirement properly, I think the above WP_Query returns the required posts and to get the categories you can use 'get_terms' -- Updated answer with example and links